# MDX Query: How to use where condition in query using filter()

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, ssrs-2008, ssas, mdx

Need Suggestions for below mdx query. It's giving syntax error. trying to calculate total sales where pop2019 larger than 5000 & GDPgrowth more than 1

[Schema link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYr43.png)

```
SELECT
{[Measures].[Sales]} ON 0,
{[Dim Company Info].[LOC].ALLMEMBERS} ON 1
FROM [Database] where (filter ([Dim Company Info].[Loc].members],[Measures].[pop19]>5000, [dim company info].[loc].members,[measures].[gdp growth]>1)
```

Comment: Is it due to the missing opening bracket before members?  `[Dim Company Info].[Loc].members]`

Answer (score 1):

Make the corrections to your query

> SELECT {[Measures].[Sales]} ON 0, {[Dim Company
> Info].[LOC].ALLMEMBERS} ON 1 FROM [Database] where (filter ([Dim
> Company Info].[Loc].members],[Measures].[pop19]>5000, [dim company
> info].[loc].members,[measures].[gdp growth]>1)

```
SELECT
{[Measures].[Sales]} ON 0,
{
filter([Dim Company Info].[LOC].ALLMEMBERS,[Measures].[pop19]>5000 and [measures].[gdp growth]>1)
}

ON 1
FROM [Database]
```